# Jquery: Append div only once 'on click'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a `section` to a `div` on the click of a button.

I want the `section` to be appended only on the first click, the code that I use below appends a `section` every time I click the `div`.

How should I go about this?

```
$("#nextractorapply").click(function () {
    $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
});
```

Comment: If this is the only thing that the button will do, have you considered disabling the button to prevent the user from continuing to click on it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use `one()`, which fires only once

```
$("#nextractorapply").one('click', function () { 
    // executes only once

     $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
});

$("#nextractorapply").on('click', function () { 
    // executes every time

    // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: The problem is I will have some events inside the click function that have to be executed everytime I click the button. I want only the append to happen once and the other events to execute normally once the button is clicked.

Comment: @adeno Thank you so much for that. I used the `$("#nextractor").remove()` in the same event handler which works somehow but assuming I have multiple appends to do, the number of lines of code would increase. Your method is much more simpler and effective :)

Answer (score 16):

Use a conditional to determine if it's there.

```
$("#nextractorapply").click(function () {
    if($('#nextractor').length < 0){
        $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use some kind of a condition that prevents its appending multiple times.

```
var counter=0;
$("#nextractorapply").click(function () {
    if(counter<=0){
        $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
        counter++;
    }

    //YOUR OTHER STUFF THAT YOU NEED TO EXECUTE ON EVERY CLICK
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.unbind()`

```
$("#nextractorapply").unbind().click(function () {
    $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a variable and fire event if variable is set as true or false.

```
var _clicked = false;

$('.element').click(function(){
  if(!_clicked){
   _clicked = true;
   console.log('event fired');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the element has a default class, append html.
For example you could add a class to html code like : class="first", and after first click remove that class.

A code something like this :

```
var element = $("#nextractorapply");
    if(element.hasClass("first")){
          $("#main").append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
          element.removeClass("first");
    }
```

And then after first click, the "first" class will be removed from your html and Jquery will not append any further html.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nextractorapply").click(function () {
    $("#main").empty().append('<section id="nextractor" class="five"> </section>');  
});
```