# Appending a div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and a div, i want to append this div **once** every time i click on the button, but i have a problem, the HTML code for this div is very large and i don't want that, so my question is there another method to append this div without putting the whole code in my js code? and another problem i want to append the div once only on each click but it appends it multiple times, Here is an example of what I'm talking about, i replaced my large HTML code with a small one, so here is my code:

```js
$(".appendbtn").click(function () {
   $(".appendme").append('<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>');
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>
<button class="appendbtn" type="button">Click to append</button>
```

Comment: checkout the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34476766/2724173

Comment: You called the object you insert as the object to insert

Comment: For the first part of question the answer could be: [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) the html from your server. For the second question it's enough to add :first selector: $(".appendme:first").append(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of answers here point out your naming error ('appendme' used for the container and the item being appended) but your issue is that you have a large string that you want to append. The object that you want to append could be placed within a script tag:

```
<script type="text/html" id="appendTemplate">
    <div>The div that should be appended</div>
</script>
```

And now your append code will be:

```
$(".appendbtn").click(function () {
    var template = $('#appendTemplate").html();
    $(".appendme").append(template);
});
```

When the button is clicked, the html content of the script tag is read into the variable 'template' which you then append to your target element.

Comment: Script element can not have Div inside.

Comment: Not sure about the down vote? Just guessing but has someone not realised text/html is a perfectly valid type for a script tag?

Comment: Thought so. Arun - yes they can. Script tags are **not just for javascript**.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Thank you @AndyP9, you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

Easy to fix by adding a container.

This should do the trick:

```js
$(".appendbtn").click(function () {
   $("#divcontainer").append('<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>');
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="divcontainer">
  <div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>
</div>
<button class="appendbtn" type="button">Click to append</button>
```

Comment: what about the other part of the question? do you have any idea if i can append my div using another way other than this one because the html code for it is very large?

Comment: @jessica as far as i know this is the shortest way, it is already very short because we are using jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the `<div>` you append to `.appendme` also has a class of `.appendme`. So when you click the button, the new `<div>` is being appended to every other new `<div class="appendme">` that has been appended.

To fix this, remove the class or rename the class of the new `<div>` being appended.

```js
$(".appendbtn").click(function () {
   $(".appendme").append('<div>The div that should be appended</div>');
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>
<button class="appendbtn" type="button">Click to append</button>
```

Comment: what about the other part of the question? do you have any idea if i can append my div using another way other than this one because the html code for it is very large?

Comment: Is the HTML code contained somewhere? In another element on the page? In a file?

Answer (score -1):

I would do like that :

```js
$(".appendbtn").click(function () {
   $(".appendme:last").append(getHtml());
});

function getHtml(){
  return '<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>';
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="appendme">The div that should be appended</div>
<button class="appendbtn" type="button">Click to append</button>
```

upd: function for html (from comment)

Comment: what about the other part of the question? do you have any idea if i can append my div using another way other than this one because the html code for it is very large?

Comment: I would just put it into some js function, and call it to return needed html